# How to write a loop so that R can produce results after finishing certain number of rows?

Tags: r, for-loop, foreach, parallel-processing

I have a list of over 1 million rows of URLs that I'm going to scrape, and I'm doing it in parallel. However, it takes more than the expected time to run. So, I'm thinking to break it into multiple loops and produce results every 20,000 rows as well as printing out the time it took to run each loop. Is it possible to do that?

I created a scrape function called `URL_Scrape`, and the list of URLs is called `URLs_List`

Here is my code to do the scraping in parallel

```
no_cores <- detectCores()-1
cl <- makeCluster(no_cores)
clusterEvalQ(cl, library(Rcrawler))

system.time({
  Result <- parLapply(cl, URLs_List, URL_Scrape)
})
stopCluster(cl)
```

Any advice is greatly appreciated.

Comment: There are some packages out there to add a progress bar to `parLapply()`.